# Webpack autoprefix not working with suggested configuration

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, sass, webpack

I'm trying to get sass compilation to work with webpack using [`sass-loader`](https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader) and autoprefixer and [`postcssloader`](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader). The sass compilation is working successfully. However following along with the documentation for autoprefixing isn't working:

> Add PostCSS Loader to webpack.config.js. Put it before css-loader and style-loader. But after sass-loader, if you use it.

So with just sass working, I had

```
loaders: [
    {
       test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
    }
],
sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")]
}
```

But reading the above, it seems like what I need is something like this.

```
'loaders': [
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["sass"]
    },      
    {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1',
            'postcss-loader'
        ]
    },
    {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ["style", "css"]
    }
],
sassLoader: {
    includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./build")]
}
```

Also regarding:

> Then create postcss.config.js:

I have made that file and put this inside

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('precss'),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

However, I get the following error

> Invalid CSS after "...load the styles": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "var content = requi" in /path/to/scss/index.scss

and everything breaks. What's wrong with this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

For my project, I arranged loaders in the following order to make it work with `scss` files.

```
loaders: [
  'css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1',
  'postcss-loader',
  'sass-loader'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found success with doing something like this:

```
module.exports = {
   module: {
     loaders: [
       {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: { presets: ["es2015", "stage-0", "react", "react-hmre" ]}
       },
       { 
        test: /\.scss$/, 
        loaders: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "postcss-loader", "sass-loader"] 
       }
     ]
   },
   postcss: function() {
     return [
       require('precss'),
       require('autoprefixer')
     ];
   }
};
```